# Can I customize simpleUML in Android Studio 3.6.2?

Tags: android-studio

I install simpleUML plugin in Android Studio and add the project class diagram. I find the diagram is too complex, all most class included the system automatically generated class are added, it's hard to browse even if I have toggled automatic layout, you can see Image 1.

1: Can I customize simpleUML? I don't hope to add the system automatically generated class such as `com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.databinding.TaskItemBinding` into diagram.

2: I hope to generate the diagram only for these files under the folder *data*, I right-click the folder *data* and select *Add to simpleUML Diagram* ( Image 2), but I only add a blank class diagram, why?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know why the problem, it seems to be ok, but i was searching a little bit and i found that Visual Paradigm plugin, it seems works better, would be good prove other ones. But before install the plugin, you need install Visual Paradigm. So i hope this helps a little bit, good luck.
Visit:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2385/66578_creatingauml.html

Comment: Thanks! but I can't find any menu item about Visual Paradigm EE, I use Kotlin, and Android Studio is V3.6.3

Comment: Hi!, did you install the sofware Visual Paradigm?

Comment: In this page you can find steps to integrate VP in Android Studio  https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/technical-support/running-vp-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to switch SimpleUML, there is another interesting plugin which I have found, called **Code Iris**. As you have mentioned, you will be able to customize the diagram. Jetbrains says it as

> This plugin visualizes the modules, packages and classes of your
>   project. It's like a UML based "Google Maps" for your Source Code.

It has lot of features like;

- parsing groovy and java source code
- visualize modules and their dependencies
- visualize classes and their dependencies
- visualize packages and their classes
- filtering of classes and packages
- highlighting of classes and packages
- basic structural metrics
- manual layouting
- organic layouting based on dependencies
- navigate from and to class

You may read more about the plugin here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324-code-iris

Comment: @HelloCW could you tell me is there any feature absent in Code Iris, that you are looking for?

Comment: is it OK for you to come out of Android Studio and use another software? I can recommend you StarUML then - http://staruml.io/